# wsl2上にてdocker composeを行いinfluxdbとgrafanaコンテナを生成するが,grafanaのData Sourceとしてinfluxdbを登録できない

Tags: docker

influxdbの学習の為環境を構築しています。
wsl2上でdocker composeを行い,influxdbとgrafanaのコンテナを生成し、grafanaのdata sourceにinfluxdbを登録させたいのですが、接続テストの際に以下のエラーメッセージが表示されデータソースとして認識されません。

```
InfluxDB returned error: error reading influxDB
```

環境:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx>wsl --version
WSL バージョン: 2.0.9.0
カーネル バージョン: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg バージョン: 1.0.59
MSRDC バージョン: 1.2.4677
Direct3D バージョン: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore バージョン: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows バージョン: 10.0.19045.3570
```

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:32:12 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:32:12 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.24
  GitCommit:        61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.9
  GitCommit:        v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.21.0
```

使用しているdocker-compose.ymlは以下となります。

```
version: "3"

services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.7.3
    container_name: influxdb-local
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./influxdb2_data:/var/lib/influxdb2
      - ./influxdb2_conf:/etc/influxdb2
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=password
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=organization
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=bucket
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=AaBbCcDdEeFf

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:10.2.0
    container_name: grafana-local
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
```

なお、初回docker compose up時にはマウント箇所のPermission Errorが発生する為、wsl2上でsudo chown 472 grafana -Rを行い、その後でgrafanaをrestartしています。

こうして生成したgrafanaにアクセスし、influxdbのデータソース設定を行いました。
以下grafanaのデータソース設定です。記述の無い項目には既定値を用いました。

```
Name: InfluxDB
Query language: InfluxQL
URL: http://influxdb-local:8086
Database: bucket
User: admin
Password: password
HTTP Method: Get
```

token設定も試行錯誤したのですが、結果が変わらない為ここでは省略。

wsl2上のdocker composeで同様の構築事例があれば教えて下さい。

---

この後に調査として以下を行いました。参考まで。

調査1:
influxdb-localの名前解決を確認。
まずdocker network inspectを行い,influxdb-localのipアドレスを調査。対象のipアドレスが172.18.0.2である事を確認。

```
$docker network inspect
"Containers": {
    "27ad9f3980e8e1c71a08492db0e0214b2ed2d855cae0efb621d4da6be7b1415c": {
        "Name": "influxdb-local",
        "EndpointID": "8637b8755cde4b593b0a9fed577f8609171ad36b0bf692e9accb5d6c9ac69d02",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "ca05d21016dac8dda3ac6dfe0ca50dfe6055cbdeaf422df641ed5935665856aa": {
        "Name": "grafana-local",
        "EndpointID": "e5a604171bb31212359a6516ca50ce8dc1cdee29447ea545c9e8ffbb5f3642cf",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
```

その上で、docker exec -it grafana-local bash後にgrafana-local上でping influxdb-localを実行し,目的のipアドレスに届く事を確認。

---

調査2:
さらに、grafanaデータソースのurlにipアドレスを設定し接続テストを試す。
`URL: http://172.18.0.2:8086`

この場合のエラーは以下となりました。

```
Get "http://172.18.0.2:8086/query?db=bucket&epoch=ms&q=SHOW+measurements": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) error reading influxDB
```

---

調査3:
grafanaコンテナからのnslookup

```
$ nslookup influxdb-local
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11:53

Non-authoritative answer:

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   influxdb-local
Address: 172.18.0.2
```

---

調査4:
grafanaコンテナからのcurlその1 (一部抜粋。社内proxyからのエラーが含まれるようだったので、名前解決が失敗か)

```
$curl http://influxdb-local:8086
<p>This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.</p>
```

---

調査5:
grafanaコンテナからのcurlその1(一部抜粋)

```
$curl http://172.18.0.2:8086
<p>The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.</p>
```